# /var/log/rundeck -- rundeck.audit.log -error or warning

Tags: rundeck

I see this message under /var/log/rundeck -- rundeck.audit.log.
Is that something I should be concern?
Any config change that needs to be updated?

ACLRule</etc/rundeck/admin.aclpolicy[1][type:node][rule: 1]>{'Admin, all access.' context={proj## Heading ##ect='.*'} type='node' for: { group='admin'} allow=[*]} REJECTED for action read => REJECTED (0ms)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somebody from the admin group tried to read some nodes denied by the ACL policy rule in a specific project. Just the ACL working.